# Limit the size of the textview horizontally

Tags: layout, textview, android, android-gui

I have this text view

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/name"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#ffffff" 
          android:textSize="16sp"  
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
```

The problem is if the text is bigger then the textview can display it just stop displaying it looks something like this `|some unfinished tex|` I want to have dots on the end in this way it will be more clear to the user that this is unfinished and it it is displayed only a part of the text

I would prefer something like this `|Some unfinished te..|`

How to implement this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried setting [android:ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize) paremeter to "end"?

Answer (score 0):

I used the hack by checking text size every time i set it to textview and appended those dots after a substring of text.I don't know it is bad practice or so!! :P

Answer (score 0):

you can do this type;

```
public String getChar(String inputstring){
String substring;
if(inputstring.length() >0 ){
substring=inputstring.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex);
}
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(substring);
sb.append("....");
return sb.tostring();
}
```